# How do I find the arc length of a curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, arc-length

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArcLength.aspx

I see there is a formula for the arc length on that web page, and I think I understand it ...

[image: arc length in polar coordinates]

**What I don't understand is: how do I use that formula if I have a third variable $t$ as a parameter, and I know the functions $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$?**

The $\theta(t)$ I am working with is $$\theta(t) = \theta_i(1-t)+\theta_ft$$ where $\theta_i$ and $\theta_f$ are the (constant) initial and final angles, so I think this theta just increases linearly, not sure if that helps simplify things.

The $r(t)$ is not as simple as the theta but it is log-linear increase between the (constant) initial and final radius: $$r(t) = r_i^{1-t}\,r_f^t$$

I know that $t$ is going from $0$ to $1$, but **I want to get rid of the $t$ and write $r$ as a function of $\theta$ somehow...**

How do I find what $ds$ is from the parametrized versions of $r$ and $\theta$?

---

Sorry if it's kinda noob question, I'm not good at this stuff. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Use $d\theta=\dot{\theta}dt$.

Comment: @J.G. thanks, i know that means the derivative of $\theta$ with respect to time right?

Comment: @J.G. so, $\theta'(t) = - \theta_i + \theta_f$ for my problem, I think...

Comment: Right, so an integral over $\theta$ can just be rescaled to the integral over $t$ that gives the arc length.

Comment: I'm trying to test points with nice numbers, i just choose pythagorean triples so the radius is an integer... I am trying (3,4) to (5,12) so $$r_i=5$$ and $$r_f=13$$ and $$\theta_i = \arctan(4/3)$$ and $$\theta_f = \arctan(13/5)$$. Now I also know $$d\theta/dt = -\theta_i + \theta_f = -\arctan(4/3) + \arctan(13/5)$$ and I know $$r(t) = 5^{1-t}\cdot 13^t$$

Comment: I guess I can also find $$dr/dt = 5^{1-t}\cdot 13^t \cdot \ln(13/5)$$

Comment: Pro tip: plug in specific values as late in your calculation as you can, especially with calculus problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are given $t\mapsto r(t)$ and $t\mapsto\theta(t)$ we can set up the parametric representation $t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ with
$$x(t)=r(t)\cos\theta(t),\quad y(t)=r(t)\sin\theta(t)\ .$$
It follows that
$$x'=r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\>\theta',\quad y'=r'\sin\theta+r\cos\theta\>\theta'\ ,$$
where the $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $t$. This implies
$$x'^2+y'^2=r'^2+r^2\>\theta'^2\ ,$$
so that
$$ds=\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}\>dt=\sqrt{r'^2(t)+r^2(t)\,\theta'^2(t)}\>dt\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the purpose of integration, it is more convenient to use the common variable $t$.

Express the integrand in terms of $t$,

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta} =\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\theta} = \left(\frac{r_f}{r_i}\right)^t\left[1+\left(\frac{r_i}{r_f}-1\right)t\right] \frac{1}{\theta_f-\theta_i}$$

Thus, the arc integral becomes

$$L=\int_A \sqrt{r^2+\left( \frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}  d\theta$$

$$=(\theta_f-\theta_i) \int_0^1  \left(\frac{r_f}{r_i}\right)^t \sqrt{ r_i^2+\frac{1}{(\theta_f-\theta_i)^2}\left[1+\left(\frac{r_i}{r_f}-1\right)t\right]^2} dt$$

or,

$$L= \int_0^1  \left(\frac{r_f}{r_i}\right)^t \sqrt{\left[(\theta_f-\theta_i) r_i\right]^2+\left[1+\left(\frac{r_i}{r_f}-1\right)t\right]^2} dt$$